# How to use plain constant file in production wihtout minify in angular 5?

Tags: angular

Is there any way we can use the constant file in build as it is ? As I have url's in the constant file might want to change them without generating a new build. As file is included in main js file in dist's script folder are minified.

Comment: If your URL changes after build time, it should not be in the environment variables in the first place I believe.

Comment: After minification values of the constant file field will not change, so no worries.

Comment: Can i unminfied bundle which contain contant file and update variable values ?